# Can bit-level operations ever be "fast" in software?

Tags: c, cpu-architecture

Let me clarify the soft-sounding title straight away. This is actually something that has been nagging me for quite a while now, despite feeling like a pretty basic question.

Many languages give a faulty impression of efficiency by letting the developer play with bits, such as the`bool.h` C header which, as I understand it, is essentially just an int with a wrapper around it. Essentially, the byte seems to be the absolute lowest atomic unit of computation  in C - `bool x = 0` is not faster/more memory efficient than `int x = 0`.

What I'm wondering is then, what do we do when we want to implement an algorithm that is inherently tied to loading and manipulating single bits, such as decoding binary codes, unweighted graph connectivity problems and many others? In other words, is the atomicity of the byte an inherent property of modern CPUs or could we *theoretically* rival the efficiency of an ASIC just by using machine code?

EDIT: Pretty surprised by the downvotes, but I suppose people just didn't understand what I was asking. I think a really good, canonical example is traversing a binary tree (or any other sequential list of yes/no questions really). What I was wondering is if modern cpu architectures are fundamentally poorly equipped to do this (as compared to an ASIC/FPGA, that is), or if this is an artifact of some abstraction layer (language/kernel/etc). Mark's answer was good though (although I'd love a reference to the mentioned architecture extension)

Comment: `bool.h` and booleans in general aren't an efficiency feature. Your question is based on a misconception.

Comment: There *are* some architectures with bit-addressable memories. So C compiler for such an architectures *may* optimize some instructions to use these specifics. Or provide some extension commands to give this ability to the programmer.

Comment: Good thing that the question isn't about the efficiency of the bool type then

Comment: Also, the power of an ASIC isn't in manipulating individual bits.

Comment: It's call bit field.

Comment: The down votes are for the nature of the question. Stack Overflow questions are supposed to be about solving concrete problems, not soliciting advice or opinions. I think this is a bit short signed on the part of SO, because I think some of the best answers on SO are opinions. BUT that is  probably why you were down voted (by others, not me).

Comment: No big mystery. Application-specific (the AS in ASIC) solutions will _virtually always_ work better in some fashion than general purpose ones (in this case CPU's). If they didn't, why would someone pay to implement them? The general purpose solution is shaped by market forces as well. As late as the 80's there _were_ bit-addressable architectures in use, e.g. Burroughs machines. Eventually bytes proved to be the best use of processor transistors and other resources in average applications.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No you can't rival the efficiency of an ASIC. An ASIC means you can replicate parallel bit streams as much as you have budget for on the chip. You just cut and paste your HDL until you fill your die space.  A CPU only has a limited number of cores.

I'm guessing that you think that bit operations like `z = (x|(1<<y)>>4` are slow and yes, all that bit shifting is extra overhead. But that is just accessing the bits. The bit operations (OR, AND, etc) are all as fast as you can get on modern CPU, i.e. 1 cycle throughput.

The 8051 architecture has a way of accessing individual bits directly, without using byte registers, but if you are worried about speed, you wouldn't consider a 8051.

Comment: No bit shifting is probably fine and all, but shifting is a byte-level operation really. I'm talking about loading and flipping single bits.

Comment: @BenjaminLindqvist why should loading and flipping single bits be any slower than arithmetic operations?

Comment: Not slower on an absolute level, but certainly slower *per bit manipulated* :)

Comment: You can manipulate *more than one bit* in a single operation.

Comment: Well clearly batch processing is always more efficient. But sometimes your application simply does not allow it.

Comment: If you have packed your information into bits, the gain is in memory requirement.

Comment: CPUs are not bit stream oriented if that is your question.  Processing a compressed bit stream (like music or video or images, that use huffman encoding) is painful on a CPU that only accesses bytes.   There are architecture extensions on some CPUs that let you sort of have a bit stream, but these are not accessible through the C language. You need to write assembly or pseudoassembly to get those.

Comment: Yes you got the gist of my question exactly. If you edit that in you have my checkmark - preferrably with a reference to this architecture extension you mentioned.

Comment: Back to question: "Can bit level access be fast?" Yes. If there is bitstream processing you only have a fraction of the file access, often the slowest operation. Yet accessing the next bit from a byte is very quick.

Comment: I worked on an architecture once (that doesn't exist anymore) that had bit stream manipulation instructions: https://www.design-reuse.com/news/8418/3plus1-technology-emerges-stealth-mode-heterogeneous-multiprocessor-architecture-creates-power-performance-coolprocessor-family.html but @WeatherVane brings up the most interesting part in that bit access, it turns out, is not the rate limiting step in most processors these days, but file IO and even memory IO are much slower than the processors.

Comment: That said, if you solve the IO problem, an ASIC will always win.  Look at Bitcoin mining: https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Mining_hardware_comparison, ASICs are 1000x faster than GPUs and 1000000x faster than CPUs.

Answer (score 2):

By convention, a byte is the smallest addressable piece of memory in a computer.  The number of bits that a byte has can differ from one system to another.

In the case of x86, there are instructions to move bytes from memory to a register and back, and instructions to manipulate values in registers.  I can't speak to other architectures, but they most likely work in a similar way.

So anytime you need to manipulate some number of bits you need to do so a byte (or word, i.e. multiple bytes) at a time.

Comment: "By definition, a byte is the smallest addressable piece of memory in a computer." --> Disagree. See [comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41577110/can-bit-level-operations-ever-be-fast-in-software#comment70359099_41577110)  C imposes a minimum "byte" size, but that limits C code addressing, not the computer.  Further code could use  a bit field `unsigned x:1; ... x = y;` and the compiler generates code that addresses 1 bit and sets it.

Comment: I'd change the wording to "by convention" not "by definition".

Answer (score 1):

I also don't know why this question got so many downvotes, the question:

> In other words, is the atomicity of the byte an inherent property of modern CPUs or could we theoretically rival the efficiency of an ASIC just by using machine code?

seems reasonable to me.  It's certainly not a bad compared to many questions on stackoverflow.

The answer is: **no CPUs can't match the efficiency of an ASIC**.

However, the reason is not because CPUs are manipulating bytes instead of bits.  Instead it's because most of the work that CPUs do to process an instruction is involved with loading it from memory, decoding it, tracking dependencies, etc., rather than performing the actual arithmetic operations on bits or bytes that the instruction directs the CPU to perform.

A good explanation of this is shown in the [following presentation](http://llvm.org/devmtg/2014-10/Slides/Baker-CustomHardwareStateMachines.pdf) from the 2014 LLVM developers meeting.  The presentation shows how OpenCL can be used to generate custom FPGA hardware.  Slides 12 to 28 show a nice pictorial example of overhead associated with a CPU algorithm and how custom hardware can remove much of this overhead.